# Adjustbox, can I move caption with the content using lap?

Tags: adjustbox

Let's say I want to include an oversized margin figure that is allowed to stick into the normal text area using `adjustbox`, perhaps by something like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{marginfigure}
\adjustbox{lap=-\marginparwidth,caption=Caption,nofloat=figure}{\includegraphics[width=2\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{marginfigure}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

This results in

[image]

which is mostly what I want, except for the placement of the caption.

Is it possible to have the caption move along with the actual content of the `adjustbox`? I'm not concerned with the content overlapping the normal text block (this will be taken care of in another way).

I know there are probably a lot better ways to do what I'm trying to do, but I'm editing a large document and prefer to do something similar to what the original authors have done, keeping their choice of syntax in some user defined macros.

Comment: What does this mean: "Is it possible to have the caption move along with the actual content of the adjustbox? "

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Adjustbox sets the caption, but it's located in the same place as it would be without the `lap=-\marginparwidth`. I had expected that the caption would be set inside the same box that is "moved" by the `lap` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I understand you correctly, then you want the caption centered below the image, right?

You need to first add the caption, then apply lap. This is best done by two nested `\adjustbox` calls as the (no-)float options are processed always after the normal ones:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{marginfigure}
\adjustbox{varwidth=\linewidth,lap=-\marginparwidth}{%
    \adjustbox{center,caption=Caption,nofloat=figure}{\includegraphics[width=2\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}}%
}
\end{marginfigure}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the caption on the left change `center` to `left` and the `lap` amount to `-1.5\marginparwidth`.